# Rails 3, Cancan: defining ability on custom controller action acting on collection, not member

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have a RESTful controller for the model `UserResource`. I added a custom action called `remote_update` and I want to limit that action only if the user's id matches:

```
if user.has_role? :admin
  can :manage, :all

elsif user.has_role? :regular
  can [:remote_update], UserResource, :user_id => user.id

end
```

I am using `load_and_authorize_resource` in the controller.

The problem is that users are still able to use that action even if their user id does not match. (To test, I am using Firebug and changing the hidden value of the id).

My route is as follows:

```
resources :user_resources do

collection do
  post 'remote_update'
end
```

end

According to https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Authorizing-controller-actions, when we have custom actions, Cancan tries to load the resource using the id, from the link:

```
def discontinue
 # Automatically does the following:
 # @product = Product.find(params[:id])
 # authorize! :discontinue, @product
end
```

I don't have an id defined because it is a POST, not a GET or PUT. 
THoughts on how to construct the ability? Thank you.

Comment: Why `UserResource` instead of `User`?

Comment: UserResource is a model that links User and Resource models. UserResource has a belongs_to relationship to both User and Resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to do an update ('remote_update') with a POST.  A POST is supposed to create, and thus should not normally have a populated id.  Thus I would not expect CanCan to do that lookup for you.

I suggest that you either:

Manually find the product and authorize it in your discontinue method,

or

Use a PUT

btw, The ability looks correct to me.